# Upload Image from iOS using ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: php, mysql, ios, image, upload

My app uploads an image and user/email/pass upon registration.  iOS to php to mySQL.  Email,user & pass & image name get saved to the db just fine.  Its just the image that is not getting uploaded to the folder on the server.  So its just that part of my code which is failing, but can anyone see where?  I have this code on my server:

```
<?
include"master_inc.php";
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------RECEIVE LOCAL VARIABLES FROM FORM
$lastname = strip_tags(substr($_POST['lastname'],0,32));
$firstname = strip_tags(substr($_POST['firstname'],0,32));
$phone = strip_tags(substr($_POST['phone'],0,32));
//$image = $_POST['image'];
$photo=($_FILES['photo']['name']); 

$password_hint=$_REQUEST['password_hint'];
$noERROR=1;
$udidposted = 9;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------CHECK IF USERNAME IS LONG ENOUGH
$username = strip_tags(substr($_POST['username'],0,32));
if(trim($username)!=='' && strlen(trim($username)) >= 4){
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------IF LONG ENOUGH THEN RUN A QUERY GETTING ALL DATA FROM THAT USER
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------IF $sql GOTTEN HAS ROW COUNT > 1 THEN USER ALREADY EXISTS----------------SET EXISTING USER 104 FLAG
if($count>0){
$username_already_in_use = 3141;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------ELSE USERNAME IS TOO SHORT?!?!-------------------------------------------------------SET USER TOO SHORT 104 FLAG
}else{
$username_too_short = 3142;}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------EMAIL FORMAT CHECK
$email_raw = $_REQUEST['email'];
if(eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@([a-z0-9-]{2,3})+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email_raw))
{ 
$email = $email_raw;
}else{
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------IF INVALID EMAIL THEN----------------------------------------------------------------------SET INVALID EMAIL 104 FLAG
$bad_email=3143;
} 

//email unique?
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count>0){
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------IF SQL FOR EMAIL RETURNS A ROW THEN------------------------------------------------SET EMAIL 104 FLAG
$email_already_in_use=3144;
}

//Secure Password Format Checks
$pw_clean = strip_tags(substr($_POST['password'],0,32));
if (preg_match("/^.*(?=.{4,})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/", $pw_clean, $matches)) {
}else{
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------IF PW NOT IN FORMAT THEN-----------------------------------------------------------------SET PW 104 FLAG
$pw_insecure = 3145;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------IF ERROR FLAGS ARE SET THEN LOG HEADERS----------------------------
if($username_already_in_use==3141 OR $email_already_in_use==3144 OR $pw_insecure==3145 OR $bad_email==3143 OR $username_too_short==3142){
header(
"location:user_add_errors.php?pw_insecure=$pw_insecure&email_already_in_use=$email_already_in_use&username_already_in_use=$username_already_in_use&bad_email=$bad_email&username_too_short=$username_too_short"); 
die();
}
else {header("location:user_add_errors.php?noERROR=$noERROR");}

//End Error Checks________________________

//-------------------------------------------------------------------INSERT INTO SQL
//Encrypt Password
$encrypted_pw = md5($pw_clean);
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`username`,
`password`,
`lastname`,
`firstname`,
`email`,
`phone`,
`password_hint`,
`udid`,
`userCreated`,
`photo`)
VALUES
(
'$username',
'$encrypted_pw',
'$lastname',
'$firstname',
'$email',
'$phone',
'$password_hint',
'$udidposted',
now(),
'$photo')"; 
// save the info to the database
$results = mysql_query( $query );

//-----------------------CODE FOR SAVING IMAGE STARTS
//This is the directory where images will be saved 
 $target = "images/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 

 //This gets all the other information from the form 
 $photo=($_FILES['photo']['name']); 

 //Writes the photo to the server 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 } 
//-----------------------CODE FOR SAVING IMAGE ENDS

// print out the results
if( $results )
{
    if($username_too_short==3142){echo"ShortUser=".$username_too_short;}

    if($username_already_in_use==3141){echo"UserTaken=".$username_already_in_use;}

    if($email_already_in_use==3144){echo"EmailTaken=".$email_already_in_use;}

    if($pw_insecure==3145){echo"ShortPass=".$pw_insecure;}

    if($bad_email==3143){echo"BadEmail".$bad_email;}



//echo( "<font size='2' face='Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'>Your changes have been made sucessfully. <br><br><a href='login.php'>Back to login</a></font> " );
}
else
{
die( "Trouble saving information to the database: " . mysql_error() );
}
//--------------------------------------AGAIN?! THIS IS FOR THE FIRST ENTRY I THINK
$sql="SELECT * FROM users";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count==1){

$query = "UPDATE `users` SET `permissions`='5' WHERE `email`='$email'"; 
//---------------------------------------SAVE the info to the database
$results = mysql_query( $query );
//---------------------------------------JUST PRINT CODE
if( $results )
{ echo( "ADMINCREATED" );
}
else
{
die( "ERRORSAVINGADMIN" . mysql_error() );
}

}
?>
```

and my iOS code I'm pretty sure is working fine:

```
-(void)callASIHTTP{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myserver.com/learn/login/user_save2.php"]];    
    // Upload an NSData instance
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.pickedImage, 90);

    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request addPostValue:self.userName.text forKey:@"username"];
    [request addPostValue:self.userPass.text forKey:@"password"];
    [request addPostValue:self.userEmail.text forKey:@"email"];
    [request addData:imageData withFileName:self.userName.text andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"photo"];

    //check if passedData is nil
    if (imageData == nil) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title:iDnil" message:@"msg:iDnil" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
        [alertView release];
    }

    //completion blocks
    [request setCompletionBlock:^{
        NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
        if (responseString == nil) {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title:rStrg" message:@"msg:rStrg" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
            [alertView release];
        }
    }];
    [request setFailedBlock:^{
        NSError *error = [request error];
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }];

    [request startAsynchronous];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know your problem..  I have faced the smilar issue..  You have to give the path for the image.. The following code will get the image from the path.. if the image is in your directory index you have to get the path little different..  Try this and let me know..

```
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
        NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"photo.jpg"];
[request setFile:[NSURL URLWithString:dataPath] forKey:@"photo"];

//IF the photo is in directory index use the following code to get the url
NSString *filename = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"photo" ofType:@"png"];
[request setFile:[NSURL URLWithString:filename] forKey:@"photo"];
```

Ok here is the code you have to write for UIImagePicker

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)thePicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)imageInfo 
{
    imagePicker = nil;

    UIImage *image = [imageInfo objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"];
    image = [image roundedCornerImage:23.5 borderSize:1];




    // Get the data for the image as a JPEG
    NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);

    // Give a name to the file
    NSString* imageName = @"photo.png";

    // Now, we have to find the documents directory so we can save it
    // Note that you might want to save it elsewhere, like the cache directory, or something similar.
    NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    // Now we get the full path to the file
    NSString* fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
    [imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:NO];
    myPicture = imageData;
    myPicturePath = fullPathToFile;    

    // Dismissing the image picker view
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}
```

While uploading the image use this code..  You will have the myPicture path set from the image picker..

```
Request setFile:myPicturePath forKey:@"photo"];
```

The following code is to get the image from the document directory and send it..

```
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

                // Now we get the full path to the file
                NSString* fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"photo.png"];
                [imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:NO];

                [Request setFile:fullPathToFile forKey:@"photo"];
```

Comment: Why do I need the path if I'm setting a uiimage as nsdata?

Comment: What is "[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"photo.jpg"]" in your code?  Im not uploading this file from my bundle, its a picked image from UIImagePicker

Comment: Please see my updated answer..  and you dont need "stringWithFormat"  you can just put @"photo.jpg".. please see my updated answer.. how you will solve your problem..

Comment: Now I have a design issue.  My code is working but validation is done after the upload to server code is called in php.  I need to fix this and I don't know if I need to create a new question or answer my own question here?  I did fix my upload code a little differently than Dilip suggested, so that could qualify as a "Answer your Question" post, right?

Comment: Yes @mars you can post your code as answer..  It will help some one in future...Just answer your own question..

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is silly, but I had a similar problem only to find it was folder permissions on the web server.

Comment: I have given the folder 777.  I think it's something in my php code but I'm not sure cause I'm not a php expert.  The code for uploading the image is right after the db code.